# Where, Select and Single in Linq: What is the most efficient use with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

As far as I know, there is not a way to select information from the output of a Single statement. It means it is not possible to write like this:

```
var playerIdName = context.Players
    .Single(p => p.ID == playerID)
    .Select(p => new 
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.Name + " " + p.LastName,
    });
```

Instead, you can write in this two ways:

```
var playerIdName = context.Players        
    .Select(p => new 
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.Name + " " + p.LastName,
    })
    .Single(p => p.ID == playerID);
```

or

```
var playerIdName = context.Players
    .Where(p => p.ID == playerID)
    .Select(p => new 
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.Name + " " + p.LastName,
    }).Single(p => p.ID == playerID);
```

but both of them seem tremendously unefficient. Any suggestion of what is the efficiency of this two statements and what is the better way to get information from a selected item apart to make two different statements like:

```
var player = context.Players
    .Single(p => p.ID == playerID);
var playerIdName = new 
    {
        ID = player .ID,
        Name = player .Name + " " + player .LastName,
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var playerIdName = context.Players
    .Where(p => p.ID == playerID)
    .Take(1)
    .Select(p => new 
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.Name + " " + p.LastName,
    })
    .Single();
```

Take(1) will get the first object that matches the filter in the Where(), Select() projects it, and Single() then executes the whole set.
The iterator in Where() will only iterate until it finds the first match.

I did not test if EF is able to convert this to SQL.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it in few hours and I will give you a reply. I suppose, anyway, that last .Single() is not necessary, being already the output of Take() a single element.

Comment: The difference is that Single() makes the type of playerIdName Player, while without Single(), the playerIdName variable will be of type IQueryable<Player>.

Comment: You are right, Single() helps to get the correct type. And putting the Take(1) after the Where works. Thank you very much.